# C# WPF Bind Custom List to dynamically created Data-grid sort not working..

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a custom list :

```
 public class HardwareTable : IEquatable<HardwareTable>
{      

    public byte SectorNumber { get; set; }   

    public byte SectionNumber { get; set; }

    public byte SectionStatus { get; set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Sector Number: " + SectorNumber;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        HardwareTable objAsPart = obj as HardwareTable;
        if (objAsPart == null) return false;
        else return Equals(objAsPart);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return SectorNumber;
    }
    public bool Equals(HardwareTable other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return (this.SectorNumber.Equals(other.SectorNumber));
    }       

}
```

I fill my List with stuff

```
List<HardwareTable> ImpDataList = new List<HardwareTable>();
ImpDataList.Add(new ImportedDataList(){ SectorNumber=1,SectionNumber=3,SectionStatus=0}
ImpDataList.Add(new ImportedDataList(){ SectorNumber=2,SectionNumber=3,SectionStatus=0}
ImpDataList.Add(new ImportedDataList(){ SectorNumber=1,SectionNumber=5,SectionStatus=0}
ImpDataList.Add(new ImportedDataList(){ SectorNumber=1,SectionNumber=5,SectionStatus=1}
....
```

And I I have a dynamically created Data grid:

```
 TabItem ReturnedData = new TabItem();
 ReturnedData.Header = "Returned Data";     
 var ReturnedDataGrid = new DataGrid();
 ReturnedDataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground = Brushes.LightBlue;
 ReturnedDataGrid.CanUserSortColumns = true;
 ReturnedDataGrid.IsReadOnly = true;
 ReturnedDataGrid.ItemsSource =ImpDataList; // When I do this it works but I cannot sort the data, also the data are not sorted when they are displayed.
 ReturnedData.Content = ReturnedDataGrid;
 tabControl.Items.Add(ReturnedData);
```

With the above approach I display the data, but the sorting does not work. I can understand that I need to bind the List to the data-grid but so far I have tried many approaches but non is working for my case.

One approach suggested that I do this :

```
CollectionViewSource itemCollectionViewSource;
itemCollectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("ItemCollectionViewSource"));
itemCollectionViewSource.Source = ImpDataList;

ReturnedDataGrid.DataContext = "{StaticResource ItemCollectionViewSource}";
ReturnedDataGrid.ItemsSource = "{Binding}";
```

But I could not even display my list. It was displaying empty cells. At least in the initial approach I could display the data despite the fact that they were not sorted.

Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: your sample for sorting does seem to work(first part). Perhaps, this code "Add(new ImportedDataList()" does not compile.